# how to implement version-control client say svn as java web-service?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, version-control

how can I implement SVN/CVS/Mercurial/Git/TFS client as java web-service? any pointers? basically I am developing a CMS in which i want to support version controlling.
But instead of new VC system, i want to support SVC/GIT/Mercurial/CVS/TFS so that it can be used with the existing plug-ins.

EDIT:
to make it more clear, I am developing an online VCS-client as a part of CMS. Which should support uploading from popular VCS like SVN/GIT/TFS/CVS.
I guess, I need to implement different handlers for different VCS-client. but the same data should be accessible from supported clients (SVN/GIT...)

Comment: You know rhat git works over http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I misunderstood your question. To achieve this you have to use one library for each VCS you want to support. For SVN this will be [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/), for Git [JGit](http://www.jgit.org/) or [gitblit](http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/) (I don't know those two, they are just an example). You have to learn each API to get the data from every VCS.

In your Java application (website) the UI should provide a browser like component to select a file in the repository. Dependent of the VCS the user choose the appropriate library will be used to interact with the repository.

Comment: okay, thanks :) so i guess the better would be to implement 1 by 1. So is there any thing do i need to take care, so that adding support for more VCS in later stages doesn't break the existing implementation

Comment: @AnkitYadav Design a clean layered architecture. The UI layer should be completely independent of the concrete VCS. It just says to the core layer: show me the content of directory xyz, ah it's a SVN repo by the way and here are the credentials. The core layer then uses your implementation for SVN (or Git, or Mercurial) repositories which does the VCS-specific stuff...